# API Platform - GraphQL Schema mapping nullable Collection

Tags: php, graphql, doctrine, api-platform.com, graphql-php

I'm pretty new to GraphQL, I'm building an API and a React App that connects to it.
I need some help defining my GraphQL schema, I can't find out what I'm doing wrong, but my GraphQL schema keeps bringing a mapped Collection as nullable...

I've been following the official docs (https://api-platform.com/docs/core/graphql/) but can't find out anything related to my problem, can someone lend me a hand?

Currently, I have an Entity named Author that has a OneToMany relation to the Entity Book:

`Author.php`

```
#[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'author', targetEntity: Book::class, orphanRemoval: true)]
private Collection $books;

public function __construct()
{ 
     $this->books = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @return Collection<int, Book>
 */
public function getBooks(): Collection
{
     return $this->books;
}
```

`Book.php`

```
#[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'books')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
private ?Author $author= null;
```

However, while the Book type comes out fine, with a required Author:

```
type Book implements Node {
  author: Author!
}
```

The Author type brings the Book collection as nullable:

```
type Author implements Node {
  books: [Book]
}
```

For it to be required, it should've been `[Book!]!`, no?

Edit: I forgot to add, I've disabled pagination, and I'm not using a custom resolver:

`Author.php`

```
#[ApiResource(graphQlOperations: [
    new QueryCollection(),
])]
```